# Disable first cell of first row in table with only CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and i need to disable input on the first cell of the first row only with CSS.
Is this possible?

I've tried with `content: " "` but it's not working (not the `:after` or `:before` because this doesn't disable the input on the cell)

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79n3pr74/

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/), 
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: I've tried with `content: " "` with out luck. I can put a background color but nothing else to disable

Comment: @zer00ne i think you haven't read the question..., i'm looking for a way to disable table cell with out JavaScript.. what javascript you want to write??

Comment: How is `content: " "` going to do what you want??

Comment: Based on the jsFiddle code you linked to (a no-no without the same code in your question BTW) there are no inputs in your table.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy Relevant code means whatever pertains to your question, please reread comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this, with `pointer-events`:

```css
tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type input{
  opacity:.5;
  pointer-events:none;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

There are two problems with this. One, IE 10 and less won't work, the input will just be slightly transparent. Two, the user can still `tab` into it.

A better solution would be to hide the input entirely, and replace it with a `:after` that is styled to look like a disabled input:

```css
tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type input{
  display:none;
}
tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type:after{
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  height:1em;
  padding:2px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid grey;
  cursor:not-allowed;
  vertical-align:top;
  opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[You can play with this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgoadbzy/).